# Creating a child applet window from a parent applet

Tags: java, applet

How do I create an applet window outside the web browser from within an applet running in that browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new window with [`AppletContext.showDocument()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html). You'll need to have a page on the server with the HTML and all. You get the context from your applet, which inherits [`getAppletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getAppletContext()) from the base class.

It'll end up looking something like this:

```
AppletContext ctxt = getAppletContext();
ctxt.showDocument("http://www.example.com/child_applet.html", "_top");
```

If you just want an external window, you can create and show a frame. It'll be a child of the applet and subject to the same restrictions. Also, it'll disappear if the user navigates away from the applet page.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
// setup all the context...
frame.show();
```